# My Tasks web part is not available

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, tasks, team-sites

In my team site I want to add "My Tasks" web part. But it's not available in my site collection.

Are there any feature I'm missing to activate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that the Project Task and Issue are lists on  your site ? You can add a ‘content query web part’ to display the project task or the Issue .Then detailed steps are like following:

1. Open the change on which you want to show the  web part  .
2. Click Site Setting >Edit Page>Add a web part >Content Query web part>Edit >Modify shared web part.
3. Set the Query to show items in the list ‘Project task’ .And change the title under Appearance to Project task .
4. Then Exit edit mode .

Here is another way to achieve this using SharePoint Designer (SPD).

1. Open the site in SPD and open the .aspx page where you want to display the lists .
2. Choose Data View >Add a data view .
3. Then click on the drop down arrow beside Project Task in the Data source details field and choose ‘show data’ .
4. Press and hold down CTRL while choosing  all the columns you want to display in the data view .
5. Drag the columns into the Data View on the page .
6. Right click the data view and choose ‘Show common Control Tasks’ .You can change the layout of the data view to full fill your requirement .

If  there is anything unclear, please feel free to ask

Comment: I expect something like this: https://radutut.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/webpart.png

Comment: As per the screen shot, It is your custom solution. You have to find its feature under **Site Collection Features** or **Site features** in **Site Settings**